# Parcel does not bundle in single file

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, parceljs, parcel

Why does Parcel bunlder my multiple modules not in single file and also css??

I try to bundle my modules and css in single file with build script after running build script but it as result I get a dist folder where includes the bundled files and its not in single files

this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mapish",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Nice application to note your workouts",
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
  "targets": {
    "main": false
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel src/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html --dist-dir ./www"
  },
  "author": "Mohamad Salman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "keywords": [
    "Map",
    "Mapish",
    "workouts",
    "mapish"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "^2.8.3",
    "process": "^0.11.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.30.1"
  }
}
```